# How does cloud 9 ide debugging of Node JS work?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

Does the cloud 9 ide running in chrome run the node.exe on my local machine (Mac)? Or is it running on the cloud 9 ide servers?

If the former, how does the browser (chrome) have permission to do this and run the exe?

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilites. You can run it locally, which starts a local server which also enables local deployment/debugging, or can use a hosted version that deploys on their machines. This is what they showed during NodeCamp in Cologne this year. But I don't know which of the services are open or closed at the moment.

Comment: Thanks - I'm curious to know which one I'm using right now. It sounds like you're suggesting that I'm using a local server if I'm debugging... how does it get to call and hook into node from the browser?

Comment: According to the GitHub page (https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9), you open the local IDE on localhost.

Comment: If you're using it on the web at c9.io, you're running it n their server. If you debug the app, you can get a message that says something like "Important: in your scripts, use 'process.env.C9_PORT' as port and '0.0.0.0' as host", which helps make sure you use the port they have opened up for you on their server.